# Wireless connectivity dropout specific to one device

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have an Acer Aspire 771G running Windows 8 which connects to a D-Link DSL-G624T wireless router. Occasionally (and seemingly randomly), I get connectivity dropouts for varying lengths of time; my other devices connected to the same router in the same location have no issue.

I have changed my wireless router's broadcast channel to one that is less busy and the problem still persists. I have this problem both when my laptop is running on battery power and when it is plugged in to the mains, so the problem is still there regardless of Window's 'wireless adapter settings' in the settings for the power plan.

The wireless card in my laptop is a Qualcomm Atheros AR5BWB222, and I have tried re-installing the driver software for my wireless card, but this had no effect.

Any suggestions on how to solve the dropouts? Thanks. :)

EDIT: I forgot to mention that when I have a 'dropout' I mean that Windows still shows a good connection strength, but am unable to ping the router.